# C++ <algorithm> sort() using object as comparison definition

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, overloading, operator-keyword

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

I'm reading this reference over here and this kind of confused me. How does sorting by using `myobject` work in the line `std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myobject)`? Also how is `bool operator() (int i,int j) { return (i<j)` overloaded? I don't understand how `()` is overloaded, but I can kind of see that it relates to how `myobject` is used.

```
    // sort algorithm example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

bool myfunction (int i,int j) { return (i<j); }

struct myclass {
  bool operator() (int i,int j) { return (i<j);}
} myobject;

int main () {
  int myints[] = {32,71,12,45,26,80,53,33};
  std::vector<int> myvector (myints, myints+8);               // 32 71 12 45 26 80 53 33

  // using object as comp
  std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myobject);     //(12 26 32 33 45 53 71 80)

  // print out content:
  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think maybe reading the same docs from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) should help. In the future, prefer cppreference. If that doesn't help, then please clarify whether you are asking how overloading works or about how std::sort uses the overloaded operator for comparison

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how () is overloaded

I guess there is nothing to be understood. It's just a member method with quite a strange name (`operator()` in declaration/definition) and which is called in a strange way (`object()` rather than `object.ordinary_method()`). That's just syntactic sugar, no black magic.

The object serves as a kind of proxy to pass a function. Before lambdas were part of the language, passing functions directly was quite cumbersome. Passing a `struct` or `class` was much easier. And a struct with an `operator()` can be used just like a function. Plus the object can store some data which is convenient sometimes.

Comment: It's not a choice, it's syntax for a Functor. `std::sort` takes a Callable type, which can be a function or a functor (a "callable" class or a lambda).

Comment: You're right, I wasn't aware that lambdas and callable classes are handled by the same template. Of course, `operator()` is the only 'method name' then which ensures compatibility with the lambda.